# Ascii text printing out of order in my Text Based Game?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, text-based

Edit: This was solved by changing my print statements to print(r""" """) the "r" prints Raw Text and ignores symbols such as "/"

I'm making a Text Based game using ASCII Graphics for my High School AP Comp Sci class. The issue I am having is that for some reason my graphics(Which are just triple quote strings") are printing not as they are in my IDE. They are always a line off or pushing a line farther than it should go. Here is a excerpt from my code that will produce the aforementioned error:

```
def draw(str):
    #This function allows the game to draw graphics
    for letter in str:

        sys.stdout.write(letter)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.0001**100)

    print('')


def clear():
    if os.name == 'nt':
        os.system('cls')
    else:
        os.system('clear')

def gLine():
    #Function Draws lines 
    draw("*****************************************************************************************************************************")

def gChurch():
    clear()
    gLine()
    draw("""                                    +
                                    |
                                   ,|,
                                   |||
                                  / | \
                                  | | |
                                  | | |
                                 /  |  \
                                 |  |  |
                                 |  |   \
                                /    \  |
                                |    |  |
                                |    |   \
                               /     |   |
                8              |     |   |
              ''8''           /      |    \
                8            /        \   ,\
              ,d8888888888888|========|='' |
            ,d"  "88888888888|  ,aa,  |  a |
          ,d"      "888888888|  8  8  |  8 |
       ,d8888888b,   "8888888|  8aa8  |  8,|
     ,d"  "8888888b,   "88888|========|='''|
   ,d"      "8888888b,   "888|  a  a  |  a |
 ,d"   ,aa,   "8888888b,   "8|  8  8  |  8,|
/|    d'  'b    |''''''|     |========|='''|
 |    8    8    |      |     |  ,aa,  |  a |
 |    8aaaa8    |      |     |  8  8  |  8 |
 |              |      |     |  "''"  | ,,=|
 |aaaaaaaaaaaaaa|======''''''''''''''''''''' """)
    gLine()

def gGameOver():
    clear()
    draw(""" 
  _____                         ____                 
 / ____|                       / __ \                
| |  __  __ _ _ __ ___   ___  | |  | |_   _____ _ __ 
| | |_ |/ _` | '_ ` _ \ / _ \ | |  | \ \ / / _ \ '__|
| |__| | (_| | | | | | |  __/ | |__| |\ V /  __/ |   
 \_____|\__,_|_| |_| |_|\___|  \____/  \_/ \___|_|   
    """)
def event():
    if Zalgo.happiness < 60:
        gChurch()
        ps("Zalgo is dissatisfied with your level of faithfullness. A thunderstorm is heard overhead...")
        chance = random.randint(1, 4)
        ps("Rolling dice...")
        if chance == 1:
            ps("You have been smitten!")
            print("You have died")
            time.sleep(3)
            gameOver()
        else:
            ps("Lightning cracks overhead, but does not strike you. Zalgo has forgiven you... You live another day")
```

This code itself causes one of the lines in the church to scoot over a lot, for no reason. I've looked over the code at least 40 times and still have not found a reason that it should do this. Here is the entire code for my game if you want to copy and paste it and see the error for yourself:

```
    #Made by Nick Pope -------------------------------------------------#
import sys
import os
import time
import random
#Screen-------------------------------------------------------------#
os.system("mode con cols=125")
    #Width of Screen 
os.system("mode con lines=50")
    #Length of Screen
#Commands-----------------------------------------------------------#
commands = ["//options, //Help"]
#Lists--------------------------------------------------------------#
activity = ["Example Activity 1.", "Example activity 2"] 
resource = ["wealth","food","land"]
#Functions----------------------------------------------------------#
def save():
    print("This is supposed to save, but it doesn't work yet")

def load():
    print("This is supposed to load, but it doesn't work yet")

def clear():
    if os.name == 'nt':
        os.system('cls')
    else:
        os.system('clear')

def back():
    titleScreen()

def wait():
    wait = input("Press Enter to continue: ")

def pI(options):
    #PI stands for Player Input 
    playerInput = (input("==> "))
    gSpace()

    while playerInput not in options and playerInput not in commands:
        print(playerInput + " is not a possible option")
        print("Do /options for a list of acceptable options") 
        playerInput = (input("==> "))

    if playerInput == "/commands":
        print(commands)
    elif playerInput == "//options":
        print("Acceptable inouts are" + options)
    elif playerInput == "//help":
        gHelp()

    return(playerInput)

def pC():
    #"pC" stands for "playerContinue" This function is essentially a fancy "Wait" function
    playerInput = input("Enter anything to continue ==> ")

def name ():
    playerInput = input("==> ")

    for i in playerInput:
        while " " in playerInput:
            print("You may not uses spaces in your name, try again")
            playerInput = input("==> ")

    return (playerInput)

#Text Functions-----------------------------------------------------#

def ps(str):
    #This function allows the game to type slowly with textwrap
    #PS is short for "Print Statement"
    typing_speed = len(str) * 5
    count = 0
    space = False
    #This  next aspect of the function works with the autotext wrap
    #To make sure that it only wraps after full words, not 
    #midway through 
    for letter in str:
        count += 1
        if letter == " " or letter == "": 
            space = True
        else:
            space = False

        if count >= 100 and len(str) < 200 and space == True:
            print('\n')
            count = 0      


        sys.stdout.write(letter)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(random.random()*10.0/typing_speed)

    print('')

def draw(str):
    #This function allows the game to draw. I made this so that when
    #displays load faster than normal text 
    for letter in str:

        sys.stdout.write(letter)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.0001**100)

    print('')

#Graphics-----------------------------------------------------------#
  #All Graphic functions start with "g" so that i don't take any 
  #names I might need later
def gSpace():
    print(" ")
def gLine():
    #Function Draws lines 
    draw("*****************************************************************************************************************************")

def gtextBox():
    draw("##########################")

def gNextWeek():
    gLine()
    draw(""" 
 _______                   __     __      __               __    
 \      \   ____ ___  ____/  |_  /  \    /  \ ____   ____ |  | __
 /   |   \_/ __ \\  \/  /\   __\ \   \/\/   // __ \_/ __ \|  |/ /
/    |    \  ___/ >    <  |  |    \        /\  ___/\  ___/|    < 
\____|__  /\___  >__/\_ \ |__|     \__/\  /  \___  >\___  >__|_ \
        \/     \/      \/               \/       \/     \/     \/
        """)
    gLine()
def gtitleScreen():
    clear()
    gLine()
    draw(""" 
___________.__              __      __               __  .__             _____  __________       .__                 
\__    ___/|  |__   ____   /  \    /  \___________ _/  |_|  |__    _____/ ____\ \____    /____   |  |   ____   ____  
  |    |   |  |  \_/ __ \  \   \/\/   |_  __ \__  \\   __\  |  \    /  _ \   __\    /     /\__  \ |  |  / ___\ /  _ \ 
  |    |   |   Y  \  ___/   \        / |  | \// __ \|  | |   Y  \ (  <_> )  |     /     /_ / __ \|  |_/ /_/  >  <_> )
  |____|   |___|  /\___  >   \__/\  /  |__|  (____  /__| |___|  /  \____/|__|    /_______ (____  /____|___  / \____/ 
                \/     \/         \/              \/          \/                         \/    \/    /_____/         
                """)
    gLine() 

def gExit():
    clear()
    #save()
    gLine()
    draw("""
___________      .__  __  .__                                     
\_   _____/__  __|__|/  |_|__| ____    ____                       
 |    __)_\  \/  /  \   __\  |/    \  / ___\                      
 |        \>    <|  ||  | |  |   |  \/ /_/  >                     
/_______  /__/\_ \__||__| |__|___|  /\___  / /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ 
        \/      \/                \//_____/  \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/""")
    gLine()
    time.sleep(3)
    sys.exit

def gHelp():
    clear()
    gLine()
    draw("""
  ___ ___        .__              _____                       
 /   |   \  ____ |  | ______     /     \   ____   ____  __ __ 
/    ~    \/ __ \|  | \____ \   /  \ /  \_/ __ \ /    \|  |  \
\    Y    |  ___/|  |_|  |_> > /    Y    \  ___/|   |  \  |  /
 \___|_  / \___  >____/   __/  \____|__  /\___  >___|  /____/ 
       \/      \/     |__|             \/     \/     \/    
       """)
    gLine()
    print("Welcome to the help menu! This game was made by nick pope")
    print("1. Go Back")
    options = ["1"]

    playerInput = pI(options)
    if pI == "1":
        (back())
def gGameOver():
    clear()
    draw(""" 
  _____                         ____                 
 / ____|                       / __ \                
| |  __  __ _ _ __ ___   ___  | |  | |_   _____ _ __ 
| | |_ |/ _` | '_ ` _ \ / _ \ | |  | \ \ / / _ \ '__|
| |__| | (_| | | | | | |  __/ | |__| |\ V /  __/ |   
 \_____|\__,_|_| |_| |_|\___|  \____/  \_/ \___|_|   
    """)
def gNorthernLights():
    gLine()
    draw("""  ` : | | | |:  ||  :     `  :  |  |+|: | : : :|   .        `              
      ` : | :|  ||  |:  :    `  |  | :| : | : |:   |  .                    :
         .' ':  ||  |:  |  '       ` || | : | |: : |   .  `           .   :.
                `'  ||  |  ' |   *    ` : | | :| |*|  :   :               :|
        *    *       `  |  : :  |  .      ` ' :| | :| . : :         *   :.||
             .`            | |  |  : .:|       ` | || | : |: |          | ||
      '          .         + `  |  :  .: .         '| | : :| :    .   |:| ||
         .                 .    ` *|  || :       `    | | :| | :      |:| |
 .                .          .        || |.: *          | || : :     :|||
        .            .   . *    .   .  ` |||.  +        + '| |||  .  ||`
     .             *              .     +:`|!             . ||||  :.||`
 +                      .                ..!|*          . | :`||+ |||`
     .                         +      : |||`        .| :| | | |.| ||`     .
       *     +   '               +  :|| |`     :.+. || || | |:`|| `
                            .      .||` .    ..|| | |: '` `| | |`  +
  .       +++                      ||        !|!: `       :| |
              +         .      .    | .      `|||.:      .||    .      .    `
          '                           `|.   .  `:|||   + ||'     `
  __    +      *                         `'       `'|.    `:
"'  `---''''----....____,..^---`^``----.,.___          `.    `.  .    ____,.,-
    ___,--''''`---''   ^  ^ ^        ^       """'---,..___ __,..---'''
"'                               ^                         ``--..,__ """)
    gLine()

def gChurch():
    clear()
    gLine()
    draw("""                                    +
                                    |
                                   ,|,
                                   |||
                                  / | \
                                  | | |
                                  | | |
                                 /  |  \
                                 |  |  |
                                 |  |   \
                                /    \  |
                                |    |  |
                                |    |   \
                               /     |   |
                8              |     |   |
              ''8''           /      |    \
                8            /        \   ,\
              ,d8888888888888|========|='' |
            ,d"  "88888888888|  ,aa,  |  a |
          ,d"      "888888888|  8  8  |  8 |
       ,d8888888b,   "8888888|  8aa8  |  8,|
     ,d"  "8888888b,   "88888|========|='''|
   ,d"      "8888888b,   "888|  a  a  |  a |
 ,d"   ,aa,   "8888888b,   "8|  8  8  |  8,|
/|    d'  'b    |''''''|     |========|='''|
 |    8    8    |      |     |  ,aa,  |  a |
 |    8aaaa8    |      |     |  8  8  |  8 |
 |              |      |     |  "''"  | ,,=|
 |aaaaaaaaaaaaaa|======''''''''''''''''''''' """)
    gLine()

#Factions Zalgo, King, Clergy, Peasant------------------------------#
class faction(): 

    def __init__(self, name, happiness, population, wealth, food, land):
        self.name = name
        self.happiness = happiness
        self.population = population
        self.wealth = wealth 
        self.food = food
        self.land = land

Zalgo = faction(
"Zalgo", 
0.100,
1,
50,
25,
0)

church = faction(
"church",
0.100,
16,
50,
25,
5)

king = faction(
"king",
0.100,
1,
50, 
100,
50)

peasants = faction(
"peasants",
0.100,
1000,
20,
25,
100)

factions = [Zalgo, church, king, peasants]    
#Mechanics----------------------------------------------------------#
def weekEnd():

    week += 1
    calculateStats(factions)
    gNextWeek()


def zalgo():
    print("Zalgo mechanics are not done yet")

def calculateStats(factions):
    for i in factions:

        #Faction Food Falculation
        i.food += i.land*0.7 + i.population*0.3

        #Faction Wealth Calculation
        i.wealth += i.food*0.4 + i.land*0.6 

        #Faction Happiness Calculation
        i.happiness = i.wealth*0.5 + i.food*0.3 + i.land*0.2
        if i.happiness > 100:
            i.happiness = 100




def gameOver():
    gGameOver()
    ps("Would you like to play again?")
    gtextBox()
    print("1. Yes")
    print("2. No")
    gtextBox()
    options = ["1","2"]
    playerInput = pI(options)

    if playerInput == "1":
        titleScreen()
    elif playerInput == "2":
        titleScreen()

#Events-------------------------------------------------------------#
def event():
    if Zalgo.happiness < 60:
        gChurch()
        ps("Zalgo is dissatisfied with your level of faithfullness. A thunderstorm is heard overhead...")
        chance = random.randint(1, 4)
        ps("Rolling dice...")
        if chance == 1:
            ps("You have been smitten!")
            print("You have died")
            time.sleep(3)
            gameOver()
        else:
            ps("Lightning cracks overhead, but does not strike you. Zalgo has forgiven you... You live another day")

    elif king.happiness < 60:
        gChurch()
        ps("The King summons you to his chamber..")
        chance = random.randint(1, 4)
        ps("Rolling dice...")
        if chance == 1:
            ps("The king ambushes you and takes your head!")
            print("You have died")
            time.sleep(3)
            gameOver()
        else:
            ps("The king forgives you, you live to see another day")

    elif church.happiness < 60:
        gChurch()
        ps("The church is disastisfied by your leadership! They staged a coup!")
        chance = random.randint(1, 4)
        ps("Rolling dice...")
        if chance == 1:
            ps("You have been smitten zalgo!")
            print("You have died")
            time.sleep(3)
            gameOver()
        else:
            ps("The disscuss better leadership techniques with you.. you live to see another day")

    elif peasants.happiness < 60:
        gChurch()
        ps("The peasants revolt and enter the church.")
        chance = random.randint(1, 4)
        ps("Rolling dice...")
        if chance == 1:
            ps("The peasants stab you 23 times..you resemble a salad")
            print("You have died")
            time.sleep(3)
            gameOver()
        else: 
            ps("You manage to convince the peasants to go home, or face the wrath of Zalgo. You live another day")
            time.sleep(3)




#Game Loop----------------------------------------------------------#

def titleScreen():
    clear()
    pCS = titleScreen
    gtitleScreen()
    ps("1. Start")
    ps("2. Load")
    ps("3. Exit")
    ps("4. Help")
    options = ["1","2","3","4"]

    playerInput = pI(options)

    if playerInput == "1":
        start0()
        pCS = start0()

    if playerInput == "2":
        gload()

    if playerInput == "3":
        gExit()

    if playerInput == "4":
        gHelp()

def gameMenu():
    clear()
    count = 0
    #When this count reaches 1, A faction has been interacted with, and another interaction may not occur
    event() 
    zalgo()

    ps("What would you like to do?")
    gSpace()
    gtextBox()
    print("1. Interact with Faction")
    print("2. End Turn")
    gtextBox()
    options = ["1", "2"]

    playerInput = pI(options) 

    if playerInput == "1":
        while count < 1: 

            ps("Which faction do you want to interact with?")
            gtextBox()
            print("1. Church")
            print("2. King")
            print("3. Peasants")
            gtextBox()
            options = ["1", "2", "3"]

            playerInput = pI(options)

            if playerInput == "1":
                ps("How would you like to interact with church?")
                gSpace()
                gtextBox()
                print("1. Treat to activity")
                print("2. Ask for resource") 
                print("3. Give money")
                gtextBox()
                options = ["1","2","3"]

                playerInput = pI(options) 

                if playerInput == "1":

                    ps("You treat the clergy of the church to " + str(random.choice(activity)))
                    value = random.randint(1, 5)*0.001
                    church.happiness += value
                    calculateStats(factions)
                    ps("The church's happiness is now " + str(church.happiness)) 
                    count += 1
                    pC()

                elif playerInput == "2":

                    ps("you ask the clergy of the church for " + str(random.choice(resource)) + "! But since you and the clergy are the church, nothing is gained")
                    count += 1
                    pC()

                elif playerInput == "3":

                    value = random.uniform(0.005, church.wealth)
                    ps("You give the clergy of your church " + str(value) + " gold! Their happiness increases by" + str(value))
                    church.wealth -= value
                    count += 1
                    pC()

            elif playerInput == "2":

                ps("How would you like to interact with the King?")
                gSpace()
                gtextBox()
                print("1. Treat to activity")
                print("2. Ask for resource") 
                print("3. Give money") 
                gtextBox()
                options = ["1", "2", "3"]        
                playerInput = pI(options) 

                if playerInput == "1":

                    ps("You treat the King to " + str(random.choice(activity)))
                    value = random.randint(1, 5)*0.001
                    king.happiness += value
                    calculateStats(factions)
                    ps("The King's happiness is now " + str(king.happiness)) 
                    count += 1
                    pC()

                elif playerInput == "2":

                    randomresource = random.choice(resource)
                    value = randint(1, 20)
                    ps("you ask the King for " + str(randomresource) + "!") 

                    if king.happiness > 0.70:

                        ps("The king is in good spirits! He grants you " + str(value) + " " + str(randomresource))
                        ps("You now have " + str(church.randomresource) + " " + str(randomresource))
                        king.randomresource -= value
                        church.randomresource += value 
                        count += 1
                        pC()

                    else:

                        ps("The king does not seem interested in loaning you any " + str(randomresource))
                        count += 1
                        pC()

                elif playerInput == "3":

                    value = random.uniform(0.001, church.wealth/3)
                    church.wealth -= value
                    king.wealth += value
                    calculateStats(factions)
                    count += 1

                    ps("You give the King " + str(value) + " gold! Their happiness increases by "  + str(value*0.001) + " and their happiness is now " + str(king.happiness))
                    pC()
            elif playerInput == "3":

                ps("How would you like to interact with the peasants?")
                gSpace()
                gtextBox()
                print("1. Treat noteable figures to activity")
                print("2. Ask for resource") 
                print("3. Give money")
                gtextBox()
                options = ["1", "2", "3"]        

                playerInput = pI(options) 

                if playerInput == "1":

                    ps("You treat" + random.choice(peasantnames) + " to " + str(random.choice(activity)))
                    value = random.randint(1, 5)*0.001
                    peasants.happiness += value
                    calculateStats(factions)
                    ps("The peasants happiness is now " + str(peasant.happiness))
                    count += 1
                    pC()

                elif playerInput == "2":

                    randomresource = random.choice(resource)
                    value = random.randint(1, 20)
                    ps("you humbly ask the peasants for" + str(randomresource) + "!") 

                    if peasants.happiness > 0.60 and peasants.randomresource > value:

                        ps("The peasants fill your order! They grant you " + str(value) + " " + str(randomresource))
                        peasant.randomresource -= value
                        church.randomresource += value 
                        count += 1
                        pC()

                    else:

                        ps("The peasants do not seem interested in taking any orders for " + str(randomresource))
                        count += 1
                        pC()

                elif playerInput == "3":

                    value = random.uniform(0.001, church.wealth/3)
                    ps("You donate to the peasants " + str(value) + " gold! Their happiness increases by "  + str(value/100))
                    church.wealth -= value
                    peasant.wealth += value
                    count += 1
                    pC()
        if playerInput == "1" and count == 1:
            print("You have already interacted with a faction this week!")
        gameMenu()

    elif playerInput == "2":
        weekEnd()
        count = 0

def start0():
    gChurch()
    time.sleep(3)
    gameMenu()

#Player Data--------------------------------------------------------#
pName = "If this name is printed something is wrong"
#Start Location-----------------------------------------------------#
calculateStats(factions)
#titleScreen()
#start0()
gameMenu()
#gameOver()
```

I have zero ides why this occurs, and any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Third block:

```
def gtitleScreen():
    clear()
    gLine()
    draw(""" 
___________.__              __      __               __  .__              _____  __________      .__                 
\__    ___/|  |__   ____   /  \    /  \___________ _/  |_|  |__     _____/ ____\ \____    /____  |  |   ____   ____  
  |    |   |  |  \_/ __ \  \   \/\/   |_  __ \__  \\   __\  |  \   /  _ \   __\    /     /\__  \ |  |  / ___\ /  _ \ 
  |    |   |   Y  \  ___/   \        / |  | \// __ \|  | |   Y  \ (  <_> )  |     /     /_ / __ \|  |_/ /_/  >  <_> )
  |____|   |___|  /\___  >   \__/\  /  |__|  (____  /__| |___|  /  \____/|__|    /_______ (____  /____|___  / \____/ 
                \/     \/         \/              \/          \/                         \/    \/    /_____/         
                """)
    gLine()
```

Comment: Why not post a [mcve] with an emphasis on "minimal"? Your question has too much detail which is irrelevant to the actual problem.

Comment: That is what I attempted to do with the first code block. Removing the "def event()" should reproduce the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the `\` are being escaped, used `\\` to display the single `\` properly.
Try this code below:

```
def gChurch():
    clear()
    gLine()
    draw("""                                    +
                                    |
                                   ,|,
                                   |||
                                  / | \\
                                  | | |
                                  | | |
                                 /  |  \\
                                 |  |  |
                                 |  |   \\
                                /    \  |
                                |    |  |
                                |    |   \\
                               /     |   |
                8              |     |   |
              ''8''           /      |    \\
                8            /        \   ,\\
              ,d8888888888888|========|='' |
            ,d"  "88888888888|  ,aa,  |  a |
          ,d"      "888888888|  8  8  |  8 |
       ,d8888888b,   "8888888|  8aa8  |  8,|
     ,d"  "8888888b,   "88888|========|='''|
   ,d"      "8888888b,   "888|  a  a  |  a |
 ,d"   ,aa,   "8888888b,   "8|  8  8  |  8,|
/|    d'  'b    |''''''|     |========|='''|
 |    8    8    |      |     |  ,aa,  |  a |
 |    8aaaa8    |      |     |  8  8  |  8 |
 |              |      |     |  "''"  | ,,=|
 |aaaaaaaaaaaaaa|======''''''''''''''''''''' """)
```

Comment: This fixed it, thanks! I'm not sure I understand though. So with all of my graphics that use "\" I have to replace with "\\"?

Comment: How would I fix the third code block I just now added?

Comment: Nevermind. For all those that see this in the future, this issue can be fixed by using print(r"""<Your text image here> """). the "r" prints Raw Text